# Does turning on SSL Logging log sensitive data?

Tags: java, security, ssl, logging

A client of ours has asked for **SSL** Logging information to debug connectivity issues. I was wondering if turning on **SSL** Logging in **Java** (`System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl")`) log sensitive information that I should not be sending to them?